# Can I annul my BA?

Tags: united-states, bachelor

I have have a BA in Visual Arts and quite literally hate my field to death and back and want to pursue engineering. The problem is that, since I have a BA already, I can't get into JC classes I need to transfer back into a 4 year(all the math classes) since my priority is dead last and unchangeable. Can I just annul my BA? All it does at the moment is block enrollment and give employers a chance to use the word "overqualified".

Comment: What is a "JC"?

Comment: @Superbest In this context it is likely to mean a US
 [Junior College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_college#United_States).

Answer (score 5):

Typically, no. That is a good thing as gaps in a cv are a lot worse than the "wrong" field.

Instead what people do is get a higher degree in their preferred field. This is where you appear to have trouble. However there is very little we can say about that, as the rules typically differ greatly from institution to institution, and even department to department. However, there are often people in departments whose job it is to help students with just that kind of administrative hurdles. So my advise is: find that person that is responsible for you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have picked one route to your target, junior college classes in your current area. Even if there were a procedure to "annul" a degree, it would not help with your priority. The people setting the priorities want as many people as possible to have a shot at post-secondary education, and you have already spent one shot on something that you now dislike. You may be able to make that work by consulting advisors there or at a four year college.

If not, consider alternatives:

- Move to a different area. Different districts and states have different policies on priorities, and different availability of classes.
- Go a more trade-school route. Get certifications that will let you work in a field that interests you better. Personally, I wish more web designers had some visual arts training.